# I need to split every two li's and append them to a div

Tags: jquery

I have a generic list:

```html
<ul>
    <li>list item1</li>
    <li>list item2</li>
    <li>list item3</li>
    <li>list item4</li>
    <li>list item5</li>
    <li>list item6</li>
</ul>
```

But I want to do:

```html
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>list item1</li>
        <li>list item2</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>list item3</li>
        <li>list item4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li>list item5</li>
        <li>list item6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The reason I can't add classes to the *[li](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)*'s is that this is a dynamic menu created in [Business Catalyst](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_Catalyst). What is the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: ok so once again i was overcomplicating it, all i needed was to add a background image to the a, and move the text under the image, that was the reason i wanted this function.

Comment: However, I am very grateful for your answers and really feel this will work next time, Thanks so much! xo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jBYqt/2/

```
$('ul > li:nth-child(2n-1)').each(function() {
    $(this).next().add(this).wrapAll('<div class="list"><ul></ul></div>');
}).eq(0).closest('div').unwrap();
```

- [`nth-child-selector`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) gets every second `<li>` starting with the first
- [`each()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/each/) iterates over them
- [`next()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/next/) gets the next `<li>`
- [`add()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/add/) adds the current one to the next *(so you have groups of 1&2, 3&4, etc.)*
- [`wrapAll()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/) wraps them with the new wrappers.
- [`eq()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) gets the first one from the set
- [`closest()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) traverses up to the closest *(newly created)* `<div>` ancestor
- [`unwrap()`<sup>*(docs)*</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/) removes the old `<ul>`

---

**EDIT:** Modified my answer to deal with an odd number of `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) method in combination with the [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/) method.

Something like this will do the trick.

```
$('li')
  .slice(2)
  .wrap('<div class="list" />');
```

Up to you to handle case when the result is odd.

Comment: This won't give a correct result. It will get all *except* the first two `<li>` elements, then wrap them individually with `<div>` elements. http://jsfiddle.net/jBYqt/1/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var f=true;
    var l;
    $('ul>li').each(function(){
      if (f)
      {
        l=$('<div class="list"><ul/></div>');
        $(this).appendTo($('ul',l));
      }else{
        $(this).appendTo($('ul',l));
        $(l).appendTo('body');
      }
      f=!f;
    });
    $('body>ul').remove()
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x9Rq5/

Comment: Almost, but doesn't remove the initial `<ul>` and wraps with `<ul class="list">` instead of `<div class="list"><ul>`

Comment: i've amended the script, to remove the initial ul, and wrap uls in divs.