# Position div pictures in 2 columns layout

Tags: css, html, layout

i have a web page with an image panel and a few div elements, **with the same width**, each containing an image.

I want to put them into 2 cascading columns with no spaces between them (except for the padding)

I have the following css code for image container:

```
.imageContainer
{
    position:relative;
    margin:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border:4px solid #333;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 48%;
}
```

This causes the columns to like like image 1 but i need the columns to look like number 2

Thank you!

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

```
.pg-main
{
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
}
.entries
{
    float: left;
    width: 800px;
    padding: 8px 20px 0 0;
}
.entries p
{
    display: block;
}
.imageContainer
{
    position:relative;
    margin:4px 4px 4px 4px;
    border:4px solid #333;
    float: left;
    display:inline-block;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 48%;
}
```

Comment: Can you please show us your HTML? Perhaps a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: You are looking for this http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: By chance do you not care about IE?

Comment: i can't make a jsfiddle becouse the whole page is dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a possible solutions using columns -- does not work on IE9 or earlier.

**FIDDLE**: http://jsfiddle.net/YjHzd/

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="block" style="height:30px"></div>
    <div class="block" style="height:30px"></div>
    <div class="block" style="height:70px"></div>
    <div class="block" style="height:70px"></div>
    <div class="block" style="height:50px"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    column-count:2;
    height: 145px;
    width: 80px;
}

.block {
    width: 40px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```

Comment: Your's is less semantically correct. If the content has two columns, it should be in two different divs. I can't even tell in your example where the second column begins...

Comment: Mine also works in EVERY semi-modern to modern browser, including IE6+, Firefox 3.6+, and all versions of Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

**Unlike many of the other solutions on this page, mine works in all semi-modern browsers, including IE 6, 7, 8, 9; Firefox 3.6 through 29, and all versions of Chrome. See below for screenshots.**

If they are of fixed widths, as illustrated, just 1) wrap your boxes inside another div and 2) do the following:

Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SqQqZ/

HTML:

```
<div>
    <div id="leftBoxesBox">
        <div class="redbox"></div>
        <div class="redbox"></div>
        <div class="redbox" style="height: 15em"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="rightBoxesBox">
        <div class="redbox" style="height: 12em"></div>
        <div class="redbox"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.redbox {
    background: red;
    width: 10em;
    height: 5em;
    margin: 10px;
}

div#leftBoxesBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 12em;
}

div#rightBoxesBox {
    position: absolute;
    left: 13em;
    width: 12em;
}
```

Internet Explorer 6:
[image: Internet Explorer 6]

Firefox 3.6:
[image: Firefox 3.6]

Comment: Just tried this solution before but this don't fit becouse i also have a single column visualization. By the way, thank you too.

Comment: IF i were compelled to have single columns (3rd party web service I have no control over, for instance), I would instead inject a bit of jQuery to split the two lists dynamically (like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806687/i-need-to-split-every-2-lis-and-append-them-to-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

Please post your HTML, it would help.

Maybe this will help :

```
clear:left;
```

after your 2nd imagediv. so the 3rd div can float without problems.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are only two ways to do this.  You can use Javascript to determine the position of the element.  Or you can create two seperate columns that have the images contained within them.  Left and Right Column